# How to configure clang-format for embedded SOQL and/or LINQ

Tags: salesforce, clang, apex, clang-format, soql

I'm using clang-format with VSCode to format Salesforce Apex code.  I cannot determine which settings in clang-format are controlling how SOQL is formatted.

So code like this:

```
List<String> myids = new List<String>();
myids.add('123');

List<My_Custom_Object__c> foo = [SELECT Id, Field1__c, Field2__c
  FROM My_Custom_Object__c WHERE Field1__c IN :myids OR Field2__c IN :myids];
```

is getting formatted like this:

```
List<String> myids = new List<String>();
myids.add('123');

List<My_Custom_Object__c> foo = [
  SELECT Id,
  Field1__c,
  Field2__c
  FROM My_Custom_Object__c
  WHERE Field1__c
  IN:myids OR Field2__c
  IN:myids 
  ];
```

Ideally I'd want it more like this:

```
List<String> myids = new List<String>();
myids.add('123');

List<My_Custom_Object__c> foo = [
  SELECT Id,
    Field1__c,
    Field2__c
  FROM My_Custom_Object__c
  WHERE Field1__c IN :myids
  OR Field2__c IN :myids 
  ];
```

So the things I want to control:

1. Break on SOQL keyword
2. Preserve space before the bind expression (i.e. `:myids`)
3. Indent selected field list

The wrapping depends on your `ColumnLimit` setting so for shorter SOQL statements it also is reformatting it into one single line, which is OK but something that would be nice to have control over.

I would assume the same settings that control C# LINQ queries would come into play but nothing in the docs https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html seems to jump out at me.

Also I am familiar with Prettier and Crustify, so my question is not about what options there are to format Apex code, but specifically how to configure `clang-format` for this scenario.